# jQuery check if image is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, loaded

I need help with the following code which doesn't work:

```
var timeoutID=0;
var currentImage=0;//first image is position 0 in arrImages array
var arrImages=[bla bla bla array of image URLs];
function slideShow()
{
   if($('#myImg').complete)//   <------- Here is where it fails as that's UNDEFINED.
   {
      //curentImage is a global var that remebembers the on-screen image array key
      var nextImage=currentImage+1;

      //arrImages is the array of image URLs
      if(nextImage>=arrImages.length){nextImage=0;}

      $('#myImg').attr('src',nextImage);

      clearTimeout(timeoutID);
      //Change image each second after previous image was loaded
      timeoutID=setTimeout("slideShow()",1000);
   }
   else
   {
      $('#myImg').load(slideShow);
   }
}
```

Basically I want to change the src for #myImg each second, provided that the counter starts after the image loaded.

**I hate the code button in the text editor for Stack Overflow!*

Comment: i am assuming you are having issue within IE correct?  In IE, `img.complete` and `load` most of the time doesn't get fired unless you inject `src` after attach event.

Comment: Haha, maybe! And by that I mean YES. Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: take a look at this blog post.  although code snippet is in mootools, but the issue is there.  also, read the comments. http://davidwalsh.name/image-load-event

Comment: You should post that as an answer, kjy112.

Answer (score 16):

'complete' is for native javascript object. so you should get javascript object from jQuery. 
like,

```
$('#myImg')[0].complete
```

or

```
$('#myImg').get(0).complete
```

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly the image gets the width and height when it gets loaded. So I guess you could check the width if the image. And as long as that is 0 the image is not loaded.

Comment: Hi, Domen. That's a good tip, only I am using the same image container to load images sequentially. So once the fist image is loaded it will always have width and height I think. Even if I change the src programatically.

Comment: @Domen What about browsers that sets a default loading image? Also what about browsers that doesn't load the image completely (show up blurred while loading).