# jquery replace span's with img's and check for img's loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery check if image is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404335/jquery-check-if-image-is-loaded)

I have a situation where I have the following markup:

```
<div class="image">
    <img class="" src="content-images/1.jpg">
    <span class="slide" rel="content-images/2.jpg"></span>
    <span class="slide" rel="content-images/3.jpg"></span>
    <span class="slide" rel="content-images/4.jpg"></span>
</div>
```

Now in the CSS all the children of `div.image` are absolutely positioned so they're stacked on top of each other.

What I am doing is that, on a certain trigger, let's say when a button is clicked somewhere else on the page, to change the `span`'s to `img`'s with the `src` set to the `rel` in each span. The images are large high-res images so they could take a while to load completely.

Using javascript / jQuery I need to show a loading message / indicator from when the button is clicked to when all the `span`'s being replaced with `img`'s finish loading.

I can't use jQuery's `.load()` because of known issues with images and cache etc.

I tried using [imagesloaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) but it doesn't seem to do what I need.

Is there any other way to do this you can think of?

Comment: You can image's `height` and `width` which remains 0 until its loaded.  Dont knw, if its cross browser

Comment: [what about preloading images on page load?](http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/)

Comment: @ocanal: thats sort of what I am trying to do. what in specific did you mean?

Comment: What are the issues with jQuery's load()? #justCurious

Comment: @undefined: I don't think this is an exact duplicate. The scenario in that solution is only for a single image, not a set like here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, if that's what you want to achieve, but you could give it a try...

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    console.log("Started loading...");
    // Get all spans to replace, and count them
    var imgSpans = $("div.image span.slide"), 
        toLoad = imgSpans.length,
        loaded = 0;
    // Now load each image
    for (var i = 0; i < toLoad; ++i) {
        // Closure to keep correct value of i
        (function(i){
            // Preload image
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = imgSpans.eq(i).attr("rel");
            img.onload = function(){
                // When loading has finished, replace span with img...
                imgSpans.eq(i).replaceWith(img);
                if (++loaded == toLoad) {
                    // ...and check if all images have been loaded by now
                    console.log("Finished loading...");
                }
            };
        })(i);
    }
});
```

[**DEMO** (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/LcctJ/)